# Can we know which block/thread find the minimum value of the device memory?

Tags: cuda

cuda `atomicMin` operation seems only find the minimum value of a device memory trunk. But, is there anyway to find which block/thread finally find this minimum value? I have compute-2.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are doing an `atomicMin` on a 32-bit value, you can use a generalized atomic operation on a 64 bit value, 32 bits of which represent the minimized value, and 32bits of which represent the global index of the thread.  A general approach is outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17411493/custom-atomic-functions/17414007#17414007).

Since 64 bit `atomicMin` is [only supported on cc 3.5 devices](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#atomicmin), I assume you are finding 32-bit minimum values.

If you are working with 64-bit values, then you can use a parallel reduction technique to carry both the minimum (or maximum) value and the index through the reduction.  [This question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31706599/how-to-perform-reduction-on-a-huge-2d-matrix-along-the-row-direction-using-cuda) demonstrates a parallel reduction approach which finds both maximum and index, per row of a matrix.