# How to use atomicCAS for multiple variables with conditionals in CUDA

Tags: cuda, atomic, compare-and-swap

I recently encountered a simple notion in programming but i stuck when i tried to implement it in cuda.
Suppose that i have thousands of elements and i want to find the closest pair between them. I use `atomicMIN` in global memory (suppose that we dont want to reduce) so if the distance which is calculated by each thread is smaller than the distance stored in the global variable the atomicCAS will replace it with the smaller value. For example i have the global variable `float gbl_min_dist`

To do this I use the following code:

```
__device__ inline float atomicMin(float *addr, float value){
    float old = *addr, assumed;
    if( old <= value ) return old;
    do{
        assumed = old;
        old = atomicCAS((unsigned int*)addr, __float_as_int(assumed), __float_as_int(value));
    }while( old!=assumed );
    return old;
}
```

Suppose now that **we want to store the index of the two points** that were closer together and for which the `atomicMIN` has successfully replaced the old minimum distance with the one calculated by those two points. What I mean is that **I only want to store the indeces of the two points that currently have the smaller distance if and only if its distance has just been successfully swaped in the global variable**

```
typedef struct {float gbl_min_dist, 
                unsigned int point1,
                unsigned int point2;} global_closest_points;
```

So here, when a thread executes the `atomicMIN`, if the value that is proposed by that tread to be compared is swapped in the `gbl_min_dist` then i also need to swap the p1, p2 with the values from the thread. If the `gbl_min_dist` is not swapped then I dont want to store the points cause this would give wrong points but correct minimum distance.

Is there any return value to check if `atomicCAS` has made the swap?

Any ideas on how to implement this within the `atomicMIN`?

Thanks in advance

Comment: BTW: Your atomicMin is wrong...you have to put the if( old <= value ) return old; inside the loop (after do {)! Otherwise you would overwrite a value that is possibly smaller when it is written after your first read and the CAS!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You could use a [critical section](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18963293/cuda-atomics-change-flag/18968893#18968893) to have each thread have exclusive access to the data while it is updating it.
2. Since your `gbl_min_dist` is a 32-bit value, if you can figure out a way to squeeze both `p1` and `p2` into a single 32-bit value, you could use an approach like the custom atomics answer I gave [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17411493/custom-atomic-functions).

If you simply use whether or not the `atomicCAS` made the first swap to condition additional code to update `p1` and `p2`, I think it's still possible to have a race condition that allows your data to get out of sync between thread updates.

Comment: In the critical section i see that we use `__syncthreads();`. Is this feasible only for atomic function on shared memory per block? Will it work for atomic operation ONLY in global memory?

Comment: It uses a global atomic operation.  The `__device__` semaphore is a global variable.  The `__syncthreads()` guarantees that only one thread per block is negotiating for the semaphore.

Comment: Any chance we could do this with an overriden `atomicCAS` ? Does critical section has any performance issues?

Comment: I don't know what an overridden `atomicCAS` is.  Yes, a critical section has performance issues, which I mention in my linked answer.  If you're looking for best possible performance, parallel reduction is usually best.  I didn't mention it because in your question you state "(suppose that we dont want to reduce)"  Parallel reductions do not necessarily require atomics even across multiple blocks.

Answer (score 1):

You could construct a critical section to atomically update the min value and corresponding point indices. The following link gives a example on how to build the CS with `atomicCAS()` and `atomicExch()`.

https://github.com/ArchaeaSoftware/cudahandbook/blob/master/memory/spinlockReduction.cu

On the other hand, I would suggest replace the atomic min operations by parallel reduction algorithm. That may improve the performance.

Comment: Even if i use reduction I would still need the atomic operation for threads that are not in the same block. For now I wont use reduction on that example, I have other examples that I do use reduction and of course I get better performance.

Comment: You could use multiple pass I'd parrallel reductions until data can be reduced with only one block.

Answer (score 0):

The way I suggest is, rather than depend on a stored distance, recompute it any time it is critical that the stored points may have changed:

```
typedef struct {
    unsigned int point1, 
    unsigned int point2;
}

global_closest_points, local_closest_points, temp_c_p;

local_dist = distance(local_closest_points.point1, local_closest_points.point2);
temp_c_p = global_closest_points;
while (local_dist < distance(temp_c_p.point1, temp_c_p.point2)
    temp_c_p = atomicCAS(&global_closest_points, temp_c_p, local_closest_points);
```

Old habits were, save rather than recompute.  But with modern processors, that's often not optimal. On CUDA, an atomic update to global memory takes more time than computing hundreds of double-precision distances.