# CUDA simultaneous atomicAdd and atomicCAS for value remaping

Tags: c++, cuda, atomic

I have a CUDA kernel where the input is a global array and the output is another array of the same size. I'm trying to *remap* the values from one array to the other conditioned by the value of one of their neighbours. The pseudocode would look like this:

```
remap(int* in, int* out, int* counter) {
    idx = threadIdx
    q = index calculated based on idx
    if ( in[q] > 0 ) {
        newValue = in[q];
    } else {
        newValue = *counter;
        *counter += 1;
        in[q] = newValue;
    }
    out[idx] = newValue;
}
```

The problem with this code is that multiple threads will try to check and update the value of the `q` index simultaneously. The real code closer to what I want to achieve would be something like:

```
__global__
void remap(int* in, const int* out, int* counter) {
    idx = threadIdx;
    q = index calculated based on idx;
    newValue = atomicCAS(&in[q], 0, atomicAdd(counter, 1));
    out[idx] = newValue;
}X
```

According to the documentation, the above `atomicCAS` does compute `(in[q] == 0) ? newCounter : in[q]` and store the result as desired. The problem is that the `newCounter = counter + 1` gets updated no matter what, whether the condition is met or not. I was looking for something along the lines:

```
(in[q] == 0) ? in[q] = (counter += 1) : in[q]
```

I do realise that the above is not syntactically correct, just trying to make it clear that I'm trying to atomize two update operations simultaneously, both the increment of `counter` and the update of `in[q]` but ONLY if a condition is met, if not I do not want either of them.

---

Hope the question is fairly clear. The question now would be, is this at all doable? Atomic update of two buffers if a condition is meet, and the value of the buffer otherwise. Or this is not doable in CUDA and I should be looking elsewhere.

Comment: A critical section is probably your only real option and that is very tricky to get correct and has limited scalability

Comment: You can't do an atomic update of 2 *separated locations in memory*. But with a bit of data reorganization you may be able to use a [custom atomic operation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17411493/how-can-i-implement-a-custom-atomic-function-involving-several-variables/17414007#17414007) to update 2 *variables*.