# Cuda AtomicAdd for int3

Tags: c++, cuda, gnu-parallel

In Cuda AtomicAdd for double can be implemented using a while loop and AtomicCAS operation.
But how could I implement an atomic add for type int3 efficiently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After further consideration, I'm not sure how an *atomicAdd* on an `int3` would be any different than 3 separate `atomicAdd` operations, each on an `int` location.  Why not do that?

(An `int3` cannot be loaded as a single quantity anyway [in CUDA at the machine level](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#device-memory-accesses).  The compiler is guaranteed to split that into multiple loads, so although there would be a hazard to asynchronously read the `int3`, that hazard would be there anyway, with or without atomics.)

But to answer the specific question you asked, it's not possible using atomics.

`int3` is a 96-bit type.

CUDA atomics support operations up to 64 bits only.  [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64397044/how-do-i-apply-atomic-operation-for-struct-on-cuda/64397986#64397986) is an atomic add example for `float2` (a 64-bit type) and you could do something similar for up to e.g. `short3` or `short4`.

You  could alternatively use a reduction method or else a critical section.  There are plenty of questions here on the SO `cuda` tag that discuss reductions and critical sections.

A reduction method could be implemented as follows:

1. Each thread that wants to make an atomic update to a particular `int3` location uses [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21788662/1695960) to create a queue or list of the atomic update quantities.
2. Once the list generation is complete, launch a kernel to do a [parallel reduction](https://developer.download.nvidia.com/assets/cuda/files/reduction.pdf) on the list, so as to produce the final reduced quantity that belongs in that location.

Comment: I understand the critical section can be used, but how could the reduction method be used in this case? Could you kindly provide some related information?

Comment: I've added some related information and a possible method.